# Laravel app as IDP, Azure AD B2C as SP using SAML2

Tags: laravel, saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

i have installed this package, https://github.com/kingstarter/laravel-saml which will turn my laravel into IDP. My SP will be an Azure AD b2c which will be handled by another IT company.

**Objective** :
Users logged in into my application and click a link to the azure ad b2c. The Azure then will request and authenticate to my laravel using SAML2. my laravel then will send some information to Azure so that azure can register or log this person.

**Question** : Im quite confuse about the SP provider settings for Azure, is there any documentation about this?. Is there any extra function / configuration i should configure / develop?

Comment: There is a guide about [Sign in by using Salesforce accounts via SAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom). It may be helpful.

Comment: if above doc not suites/ not able to configure on your side, do comment with proper error messages and CorrelationIds here.

Comment: Before implementing to azure, i tested using simplesaml as SP to connect to my laravel idp. After configuring simplesaml and laravel, im getting error with the message ‘Nameid value not set’

Comment: Please post more detials about what you tried and the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use SAML for Azure B2C you need custom profiles.

Here's an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp).

Warning: This is not a trivial exercise.